# Command line tool is (not) found depending from where it is called

Tags: eclipse, bash, terminal

I have the following snippet in my makefile:

```
test_mpi: main
mpiexec -np 4 ./main
```

When I run `make test_mpi` directly in the OS X terminal, it will work fine. When I run the same command inside Eclipse (by clicking on that make target), it will not find `mpiexec`.

`which` gives me:

```
[michael@mac test] which mpiexec
/usr/local/bin/mpiexec
```

Furthermore, `mpiexec` is not mentioned in my `~/.bash_profile`.

**I have no idea now, why Eclipse's console does not know where `mpiexec` is while the OS X terminal does.**

Comment: @geert3: Oops, didn't see that. I fixed it, but it makes no difference.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse uses a restricted PATH, overriding your system's PATH.

Have a look under

> your project / properties / C/C++ build / Environment

Switch to `[All Configurations]` and make or edit a `PATH` entry there, so it includes `/usr/local/bin`

(this is assuming you're on a C/C++ project here)